# Custom File Logging in Node-RED

Tags: node.js, node-red

As per the Node-Red [official documentation](https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/logging), I have enabled the custom logging in settings.js file as follows

```
// Custom logger
    myCustomLogger: {
        level: 'debug',
        metrics: true,
        handler: function(settings) {
            return function(msg) {
                console.log(msg.timestamp, msg.event);
            }
        }
```

The script works fine and prints the debug statements and metrics in the console.I would like to understand more of how do I apply a log function which creates to file for monitoring node-red?

Comment: Just redirect stdout to a file handle using your native OS syntax.

Comment: @Paul: I am using centos and I have tried using appendFile and defined within the return function as following fs.appendFile('message.txt', msg.event); but the content of the file is showing as undefinedundefined

Comment: No,just start your process and redirect sdtout.` $ node app.js &>> /var/logs/app.log` or similar.  Inside your code just do console.log or the like.

Comment: @Paul this works but is there a way where I can see both in my console and log file with out running the app in background?

Comment: Look at the `tee` command

Comment: @user8363477 there's a ton of options for configuring that stuff in Linux, just have a gander.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is a bit old but because someone asked on how to use log4js with NodeRed and I just completed it. Here is the code for it.
Add this in settings.js within the logging portion:

```
myCustomLogger: {
  level: "info",
  handler: function(settings) {
    var log4js = require("log4js");
    log4js.configure({
      appenders: {
        everything: { type: 'dateFile', filename: '/Users/Media/Library/Logs/node-red.log', daysToKeep: 7 }
      },
      categories: {
        default: { appenders: [ 'everything' ], level: 'all' }
      }
    });
    var logger = log4js.getLogger();

    return function(msg) {
      var level='ALL'
      switch(msg.level) {
        case 10:
          var level="FATAL";
          break;
        case 20:
          var level="ERROR";
          break;
        case 30:
          var level="WARN";
          break;
        case 40:
          var level="INFO";
          break;
        case 50:
          var level="DEBUG";
          break;
        case 60:
          var level="TRACE";
          break;
      }
      var add_msg=""
      if (msg.type !== undefined) {
        if (msg.name !== undefined) {
          add_msg="[".concat(msg.type, ":", msg.name, "] ");
        } else {
          add_msg = "[".concat(msg.type, "] ");
        }
      } else if (msg.name !== undefined) {
        add_msg = "[".concat(msg.name, "] ");
      }
      logger.log(level, add_msg.concat(msg.msg));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please consider editing the code snippet to be more concise. For instance, you could use the same line ending (either with or without semicolons) for each line. The `level` thing could also use an object literal.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect that the reason you keep seeing `undefined` in your log file is because the appendFile() function is asynchronous, and your callback is not correct. Try replacing the `console.log(...)` function with this:

```
var text = msg.event + "\n";
fs.appendFileSync('message.txt', text, encoding='utf8');
```

*(of course, you may need to format the text from the msg.event a bit differently than just using the default toString() function)*

Just be aware that you are now pausing the main event loop in node-red **every time a new log entry is written**! This may be ok for development, but you will need other techniques for a production system. You may want to take a look at an external logging library, like [log4js for node](https://github.com/log4js-node/log4js-node) ...

Comment: Do I need use the logger instance with in the flow for the outcome of each node? Any example of log4js with respect to NodeRed would be really helpful.